# Pass global variable to @State in view

Tags: swiftui

I have a global variable `public var Role = ""` so I can access it anywhere in the app. (Even though global variables are an ugly way to write code, I am decently new to SwiftUI and don't know how to change it to work with a multiview app.)

I also have a view as follows:

```
struct LoadingView: View {
  @State var isLoaded = false

  var body: some View {
    if isLoaded {
      Text("Data has loaded")
    } else {
      ProgressView()
    }
  }
}
```

I need a way to test for when `Role != ""` and then set `isLoaded = true`.

Comment: As you alluded to in your question, this is not a good strategy to use with a global variable like this. Instead, consider making it a `@Published` property of an `ObservableObject` and pass that object down via Environment or explicitly via parameter. Apple SwiftUI tutorials or Hacking with Swift will make some of these patterns more clear.

Comment: There is no way for SwiftUI to react to changes to a global variable.

Comment: you could look at using a custom `environment` value, for your `global` "Role".
See also : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment         and   
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-define-custom-environment-values-in-swiftui/  
and    
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swiftui-custom-environment-values/

Comment: I've had trouble with one of my apps in determining if I had loaded my data or not.  The only way I've found to be sure my data was loaded was to look at the data-- make sure my data file was in place and had reasonable data in it.  If you just check an environment value or a user defaults value you will get poor results.

Comment: Thanks @HalR, I used to just have a basic timer before going to the next view, and this option seems to work much better if you view the answer below. I'm getting data from Firebase, and delaying Role just a bit so it's the last thing of data returned from firebase, and the goal is to check if the variable has value, which it should if it's gotten any data from Firebase, and then move to the next view. It may not be the most efficient but it seems like a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to first wrap the `role` into a `ObservableObject`, then you can pass it as a `environmentObject` from the root, and let other subviews subscribe to any changes it makes through `View.onReceive`.

Wrapping the role into an `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class Role: ObservableObject {
    @Published var role = ""
}
```

Passing `role` from the root:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    let role = Role()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(role)
        }
    }
}
```

`LoadingView` listens to changed made to `role`:

```swift
struct LoadingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var role: Role
    @State var isLoaded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isLoaded {
                Text("Data has loaded")
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .onReceive(role.$role) { newRole in
            isLoaded = (newRole != "")
        }
    }
}
```

Another view that can modify the role:

```swift
struct ChangeRoleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var role: Role
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Role", text: $role.role)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Your `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChangeRoleView()
            LoadingView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much everything works. I found a thing similar to this here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127572 and used it previously but this is well explained for my case and it helped me fix some things with the code on the developer forum.